# Set DateTimePicker value in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to set Bootstrap `DateTimePicker` value

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ObjectClass", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{ 
    <div class="col-md-7">
        Du
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.helpVM.date1, new { @class = "dp datepicker", @value = DateTime.Now })
        Au
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.helpVM.date2, new { @class = "dp datepicker", @value = DateTime.Now })
}
```

I've tried this but it gives me no value in the view page.

Comment: instead of `@value = ...` try `@Value = ...` instead of small `v` use capital `V`

Comment: Set the values of `helpVM.date1` and `helpVM.date2` in the controller.

Comment: `Value = DateTime.Now` ,use like this

Answer (score 2):

Change `@value` to `Value`.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.helpVM.date1, new { @class = "dp datepicker", Value = DateTime.Now })
```

Comment: And when you post and return the view - what ever date the user entered gets wiped out and reset to `DateTime.Now`!

Comment: Yes I agree i just wanted to simplify the code to share with you , i normaly send value via session variable.

Comment: @drexdrex, `@Html.TextBoxFor()` **binds** to the value of model property. If the value of the property is `DateTime.Now`, then that is what will be displayed.

Comment: Yes it works. Setting the value as  model value `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, new { @class = "datepicker", placeholder = "Enter From date here...", Value = Model.ToDate })` sets back the date field with the changed model value